# Add swagger description in comments

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

Can I customize swagger description by comment viewset?
I use [drf-yasg](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

My code:

```
class MetricViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
       retrieve:
       Получить из справочника данные записи о метрике по *uuid*

       list:
       Получить из справочника коллекцию записей о метриках
    """
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
    serializer_class = MetricSerializer
    queryset = Metric.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (ApiPermission,)
```

my serializer

```
class MetricSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
        Metric serializer.
    """
    uuid = serializers.UUIDField(label='Global UUID', read_only=True)

    class Meta:  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
        """
            Настройки сериализатора
        """
        model = Metric
        fields = ('uuid', 'creation_date', 'modify_date',
                  'name', 'description', 'enabled', 'comment')
```

I want add descrription here:
[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: You may now accept it as well if it answers your question :)

Answer (score 2):

The following allows you to achieve part of what you asked. That is changing the descriptions of ViewSet's methods, parameters, and responses by using [swagger_auto_schema](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html#the-swagger-auto-schema-decorator) in combination with [Django's method_decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).

Check both links for more info.

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema

@method_decorator(name='retrieve', decorator=swagger_auto_schema(
    operation_description="Method description",
    operation_id="Method ID",
    operation_summary="Method summary",
    manual_parameters=[
        openapi.Parameter('serial', in_=openapi.IN_PATH, type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description='Parameter description')
    ],
    responses={'200': 'Response description'}
))
class MetricViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
       retrieve:
       Получить из справочника данные записи о метрике по *uuid*

       list:
       Получить из справочника коллекцию записей о метриках
    """
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
    serializer_class = MetricSerializer
    queryset = Metric.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (ApiPermission,)
```

---

#### Update

I found a bug where `operation_summary` and `deprecated` options passed to `swagger_auto_schema` are actually ignored, so I submitted this [PR](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/pull/194) to fix that.

Comment: @Vetos I would be interested to know if you ever found a way to customise the rest.

Comment: Same question. Can you please post the resulting code changes?